# Does anyone know how to deploy gnosis safe contracts through proxy and make them show in their UI?

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets, gnosis-safe

When deploying a Gnosis Safe contract using smart contracts. We're using the default

```
GnosisSafeProxyFactory(address(0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2)) // safe factory in goerli
      .createProxyWithNonce(
         address(0x3E5c63644E683549055b9Be8653de26E0B4CD36E), // goerli 1.3 contracts
            "",
            uint256(
               keccak256(
                  abi.encode(
                     "some name",
                     msg.sender,
                     address(this),
                     block.timestamp
                  )
               )
            )
     )
```

And we don't seem to be able to make these created safes show in Gnosis UI (https://app.safe.global/)

Does anyone know what are the validations that are being performed when loading a safe?

[image]